# useCallback hook: Variable in dependency behaves differently with 2 declaring method

Tags: reactjs, usecallback

I'm new to React & learning to using `useCallback`. Here's my problem:
In the code, I check if the `temp` is true. If yes then the `num` will be increased by 1 whenever I press a button (which I have already pointed to the `callbackButtonHandler`). Because my dependency array is an empty array, even after 2 seconds when the `temp` is set to false by `setTemp`, my button still increase the `num` by 1 because `callbackButtonHandler` is not re-evaluated by React, so the `temp` variable in the `callbackButtonHandler` won't be changed either. It behaves as I expected so far.

```
  const [temp, setTemp] = useState(true);
  setTimeout(() => setTemp(false), 2000);
  const [num, setNum] = useState(0);
  const callbackButtonHandler = useCallback(() => {
    if (temp) {
      setNum((prevNum) => prevNum + 1);
    }
  }, []);
```

But when I change how I declare temp:

```
// const [temp, setTemp] = useState(true);
// setTimeout(() => setTemp(false), 2000);

let temp = true;
setTimeout(() => (temp = false), 2000);
...
```

The button is not working anymore after 2 seconds. I can't explain to myself about this case. I think it is related to Javascript Closures but I'm not sure.

Comment: Have you tried adding `temp` to the list of dependencies?

Comment: What i mean is it works well with `temp` in the dependency list, but when I omit the `temp`, the function doesn't behave as I expect

Comment: That's because `temp` should live in dependencies: "The array of dependencies is not passed as arguments to the effect function. Conceptually, though, that’s what they represent"

Comment: Also, maybe in this case you don't need to use `useCallback`

Comment: Well I'm learning by a tutorial course, and it shows good example for `useCallback` there. Maybe because I only show the main codes which I have the problem so it may have confused you. Yeah I know that the `temp` should always be in the dependency, but I want to know what are the diffrerencies between 2 ways of declaring that leads to different behaviours of the `useCallback` hook.

Comment: when you trigger a `setState` all variables inside render get redeclared (unless you use useRef) a method declared under useCallback will not be redeclared unless a dependency changes